# interrupt pdfgrep after N matches found

Tags: bash, grep

It appear as though `pdfgrep`, unlike regular `grep` does not offer the option to limit searches after N matches are returned. I have a script that has to search a somewhat large `.pdf` file, and it takes pdfgrep over a minute to search though the entire file. But searching the entire document is unnecessarily inefficient, especially since I may need to run this command several times a day, waiting for command completion to get on with my work.

Since pdfgrep prints results as it finds them while searching, I wonder how BASH might be able to interrupt (cntl-C) the process (command) after N matches have been output at the terminal? Although such a feat seems quite plausible, I am uncertain how to implement such a solution.

Any suggs or ideas are welcome reading.

Comment: Beauty of open source, raise an issue, even better send a pull request https://github.com/x2b/pdfgrep

Comment: @iiSeymour: That's almost certainly not the `pdfgrep`, OP was talking about. The program included in various distributions is available under http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options I can think of

- `pdfgrep ... | head -n 1`
- `IFS= read -r line < <(pdfgrep ...) && echo "$line"`

Comment: both suggs here work as desired. Although both of these implementations work: `sr=$(while IFS= read line; do echo "$line" && break; done < <(pdfgrep  -n --context line "$st" "$sf"))` and `while IFS= read line; do echo "$line" && break; done < <sr=$((pdfgrep  -n --context line "$st" "$sf"))` is one more advisable than the other?

Comment: The first form is definitely clearer. I haven't seen the second form with the in-line variable assignment and not entirely sure why it works, though I think in either case @gniourf_gniourf edit is cleaner, since there's no need for a `while/read loop` for one line.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.3.1, pdfgrep also has the `-m /--max-count` option from grep:

```
pdfgrep --max-count 4 pattern some.pdf
```